# Revert a deleted instance in NHibernate session

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I remove objects like below with `NHibernate`:

```
var obj = session.Get<MyModel>(some_guid);
session.Delete(obj);
```

The object is now transient, and `MyModel` object with id `some_guid` is flagged as deleted object in `NHibernate` session.

Later in my legacy app, I need to **cancel** the deletion of ***some*** **objects** deleted in the session. I tried workaround below but had no luck:

```
 var e = ((SessionImpl)session).PersistenceContext.EntityEntries;
 var allEntities = e.Keys.Cast<object>().ToList();
 var item = allEntities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == some_guid);
 session.Refresh(item); // throw an exception
```

The workaround above will throw an exception `nhibernate instance was not in a valid state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity deletion is recorded in a action queue which can only be canceled by clearing the whole session (`ISession.Clear`).

You cannot achieve what you are looking for. NHibernate does not support your scenario, canceling some pending changes in a session but not others.

You could have tried `ISession.Evict`, but that causes a failure on `Flush`, because the action queue has then to act on an entity missing from the session persistence context. (It yields an exception guessing a threaded usage have been attempted but well, no, just an `Evict` on an entity having pending actions.)

You have to change your application for avoiding having it deleting objects which should not be deleted in the first place.

Or when detecting some objects which were deleted in the session should not be deleted, cancel the whole session (rollback the transaction, dispose the session, use a new one), and redo the work without deleting objects which must stay there. (If you do not use a transaction, `FlushMode.Auto` may flush deletions before you `Clear` the session.)

Or at worst, keep a copy of your objects, commit the session, and re-save them...